# Two Stage CMOS Operational Amplifier

Tags: operational-amplifier, cmos

While learning about two stage CMOS operational amplifier it is mentioned that the there is a phase shift of about -90 degrees so is there always a phase shift between an input and output signal?
and when we make a oscillator why dont we take this phase shift in consideration as we want the the total phase shift to be 360 to meet barkhausen criteria?

For this configuration it is also mentioned that we should take second pole value beyond the bandwidth value in order to avoid get oscillations that is meeting barkhausen criteria how is it possible?

[image]

Comment: *it is mentioned that the there is a phase shift of about -90 degrees* If the circuit would work at a very low frequency or at DC (static voltages) how can there be a phase shift? When mentioning phase shift you **always** must mention a **frequency** otherwise "phase shift" means nothing (exception: 180 degrees phase shift which is actually an inversion of the signal).

Comment: Most folk don't make oscillators with two-stage CMOS op-amps that incorporate frequency compensation. If, however, you are asking why the open-gain bode plot of the generalized op-amp (not restricted to 2 stages) has a 90 degree phase shift then please ask that question and don't assume it screws up an oscillator.

Comment: *when we make a oscillator why dont we take this phase shift in consideration* Who says that the phase shift should not be considered? Suppose the 90 degrees phase shift is at 100 MHz. If we then build a 1 MHz oscillator and a 100 MHz oscillator, can we ignore the built-in phase shift for both cases or not?

Answer (score 2):

> While learning about two stage CMOS operational amplifier it is mentioned that the there is a phase shift of about -90 degrees so is there always a phase shift between an input and output signal?

This is due to Cc, the compensation capacitor

> and when we make a oscillator why don't we take this phase shift in consideration

If we made an oscillator with an open loop amplifier like this, then we would take this this phase shift into consideration. Nature certainly would.

> as we want the the total phase shift to be 360 to meet barkhausen criteria?

However, we usually make oscillators with a low gain amplifier, comprising a high open loop gain opamp, with feedback components to control the gain. The phase shift of the low gain amplifier, where the closed loop gain is >>1, will be dominated by the feedback components. If these are two resistors, then the phase shift will be negligible, or 180 degrees, depending on configuration.

Comment: Thank you for your response.